# Calling a method to a method parameter using java annotation

Tags: java, annotations

I have a method

```
void checkNode(final String node) throws IllegalStateException {
  // do some checks, if something dosn't ok throws an exception.
}
```

To avoid calling `checkNode()` every time on method arguments I want to make an annotation and
mark the method parameter with it, say:

```
void addNode(@ValidNode final String node) throws IllegalStateException {
  // some logic
}
```

Instead of:

```
void addNode(final String node) throws IllegalStateException {
  this.checkNode(node);
  // some logic
}
```

Are there ways to implement `@ValidNode` annotation?
Or maybe not even an annotation, but another way to solve this problem with a method call?

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but I would create a `Node` class that wraps the string and validates it. Then, `addNode`, etc take a `Node` instead of a `String` as parameters. Much simpler than implementing an annotation-based solution.

Comment: @TimMoore yes, looks like a simplier way